Cant find role or database created in docker with Dbeaver
I have created and mounted a docker image with a persistent volume, here I added a database called develop but I cant connect through dbeaver to it. If i do it through the terminal there is no problem. Whats happening?
Probably this is super simple question/answer but after trying for some hours im turning crazy. Recently I have been trying to configure a simple database called 'develop' using docker with a container.
I have created database and the image of dockers with a persisten volume like this:
  --name postgres-container `
  -e "POSTGRES_USER=captain" `
  -e "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password" `
  -e "POSTGRES_DB=develop" `
  -v "C:/Projects/pitch-control/db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data" `
  -p 5432:5432 `
  postgres

I have also granted all access to captain for develop database as you can see here:
develop=# SELECT datname AS database_name,
develop-#        has_database_privilege('captain', datname, 'CONNECT') AS can_connect
develop-# FROM pg_catalog.pg_database
develop-# WHERE datname = 'develop';
 database_name | can_connect
---------------+-------------
 develop       | t
(1 row)

So, if I try to access to the database through powershell with captain user, there is no problem (psql -U captain -d develop).
But here it comes the problem: If i try to login using dbeaver it complains that the role do not exist:
enter image description here
I have restarted docker, the pc, check to grant privileges, nothing works.
The funny thing is: if I try to connect to postgres instead of develop database through dbeaver I can, but this is not what i want.

I tried to reproduce (on Windows), and was not able to do so. I am creating the docker using: docker run -d --name some-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -e PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata -e "POSTGRES_USER=captain" -e "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password" -e "POSTGRES_DB=develop" -p 5438:5432 -v E:/POSTGRESQL:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres:17  (Only difference may be that I am using Client 16: https://i.sstatic.net/f5gQ2vL6.png )
